# Mean change scores analysis for studying natural course of disease

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, biostatistics, lsmeans

I investigating how vision (amongst other outcomes) changes over time, assessed at time 0, week 12 and week 24 in an observational cohort, and wanted to obtain the mean change values at each time point, with p-values comparing the change from baseline. There's no missing data at baseline. I am thinking of fitting some variation of the linear mixed effects model, something like the following:

(1) `vision ~ Age * Time + baseline_vision * Time + 1|ID`

Baseline vision is being adjusted for as a covariate as is the norm, though not entirely sure it is needed when studying natural course of the disease (observational cohort). I've also adjusted for age, so that I can obtain the mean change in vision at each time point in this cohort while holding age constant.

Therefore, in the outcome only week 12 and week 24 measurements are modelled. I understand that using the `emmeans` function you can get the adjusted mean values for vision at times week 12 and week 24, i.e. `emmeans(model, ~ Time)`.

Is it possible to get the mean change values at week 12 and 24 from this model? Or do you need to fit the model with change from baseline as the outcome, so something like:

(2) `change_from_baseline ~ Age * Time + baseline_vision * Time + 1|ID`

Not sure if the model above should be fitted as ive read that modelling change scores is not a good idea, however, both should yield similar results when adjusting for the baseline value so I was wondering if it is possible to get the adjusted mean change values from model (1) ?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, *and* if I'm correct that `Time` is a factor with 3 levels (0, 12, and 24), you can get the means via

```
emm <- emmeans(model, ~ Time)
emm
```

Then the changes from week 0 are obtained by

```
contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl1")
```

That said, I am not sure what your model is doing. Are you excluding the baseline values from `vision` and instead putting it in as a covariate? What would be wrong with having `vision` measurements at all three times according to a factor `Week` having levels 0, 12, and 24, and `Age` a covariate, and a simpler model:

````
model2 <- lmer(vision ~ Age * Week + 1|ID)
(emm2 <- emmeans(model2, ~ Week | Age, at = list(Age = c(<ages of interest>))))
contrast(emm2, "trt.vs.ctrl1")

# and also compare the Age trends
(trnd2 <- emtrends(model2, "Week", var = "Age"))
pairs(trnd2)
```
````

Comment: Thanks! Yes thats right, I have removed the baseline vision values from the outcome and adjusted for it as a covariate. I am studying the trajectory of change in vision in my cohort who are all not receiving any treatment. The baseline values for vision were truncated at a value due to the inclusion criteria. Also, we expect there to be greater changes in vision for lower baseline vision values, so there may be a regression to the mean effect. I wanted to assess the mean change in vision at each time point, while controlling for baseline vision.

Comment: @s.stats It just seems to me that since you want to estimate changes from baseline anyway, it is more sensible to include the baseline condition as a factor level so that you can directly estimate those changes. "Controlling for baseline" suggests that is a nuisance factor when in fact it is of interest.